# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: набор ключей не существует

Tags: c#, iis, безопасность

```
static public string Build64(string idOrder, double Amount) {

        string StrForSign = KKBRequestStr.Replace("%ORDER%", idOrder).Replace("%AMOUNT%", string.Format("{0:f}", Amount).Replace(",", "."));
        X509Certificate2 KKbCert = new X509Certificate2(KKBpfxFile, KKBpfxPass);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)KKbCert.PublicKey.Key;
        byte[] SignData = rsaCSP.SignData(ConvertStringToByteArray(StrForSign), "SHA1");//  Набор ключей не существует!!!!!!!!
        Array.Reverse(SignData);
        string ResultStr = "<document>" + StrForSign + "<merchant_sign type=\"RSA\">" + Convert.ToBase64String(SignData, Base64FormattingOptions.None) + "</merchant_sign></document>";
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ConvertStringToByteArray(ResultStr), Base64FormattingOptions.None);
    }
```

Все пошагово сделал по этой ссылке [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: keyset does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106011/system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception-keyset-does-not-exist#)

Но не помогло исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В RSA данные подписываются приватным ключем, подпись проверяется публичным ключем. А вы пытаетесь подписать данные публичным ключем - точнее, вы пытаетесь использовать для подписи провайдер, в котором есть только Public Key.

Замените

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)KKbCert.PublicKey.Key;
```

на

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)KKbCert.PrivateKey;
```